# Anylogic Simple Truck Queuing Model

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to put together a easy truck check in model but I'm having difficulty. My main issue is that trucks don't wait one after another and move toward the guard shack. so I created a bunch of delays that simulate different position in the line so that trucks can move from one to the other till they end up at the guard shack. However, my second problem is with the moveTo block. No matter what I do it moves the agent from the source directly to the sink instead of moving the agent through the whole system.

I also tried to directly type the function; agent.moveTo(nameOfNextNode) into the On Exit section of the delay blocks but this does nothing

[See imagine of model below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Bh9.png)

Comment: "My main issue is that trucks don't wait one after another and move toward the guard shack" : you didn't show the model you did in which this happens... did the delays fix the problem or not?

And there is no moveTo block... but your nodes are not in the same network, so that's why it's moving directly instead of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The delay blocks did help organize things but when I placed moveTo blocks in between the delays it bypasses the default pull protocol and sends the unit to the next delay even if that block is not free.  That is why the moveTo blocks are not in the picture. Is there a piece of code that I can write to tell the agent to move along the path to the next node only if the next node is free?

Comment: you have a lot of other blocks in the process modeling library and there are at least 10 different ways of doing this... with a hold block, a wait block, using the delay block with a stopDelay function, etc... you need to investigate the other blocks you have and learn how to build stuff... delays and queues are not your only tools